# Calling objective c method with enum as argument in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

I am trying to use a objective c method with enum as argument in swift.The value for the argument is set based upon swift enum variable.

Swift enum

```
enum SecurityType: Int {

    case pushNotification = 0
    case touchId = 1
    case faceId = 2
}
```

My enum in objective c file look like

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ScreenType) {
TouchID = 1,
FaceID = 2,
ConsentApproval = 3,
VerifyMyIdentity = 4 };
```

My swift code is

```
let screenType: ScreenType = self.biometricType == .touchId ? .touchID : .faceID

guard let newVC = MyViewController.init(screenType: screenType) else { return }
```

In above method **biometricType** variable is of swift enum type.

Here is my init method

-(instancetype)initWithScreenType:(screenType *)type {

self = [super init];

```
  if (self) {
     UIStoryboard *passcodeStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard  storyboardWithName:passcode bundle:nil];
     self = [passcodeStoryBoard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AuthenticationViewController"];
     self.screenType = type;
     return self;
  }
```

return nil;
}

I am getting an error on init method

> Cannot convert value of type 'EnumType' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer!'

Can somebody have any idea what might be the reason behind it.

Comment: Could you post how the `init` method is defined, thats half the story.

Comment: `-(instancetype)initWithScreenType:(screenType *)type {` => `-(instancetype)initWithScreenType:(screenType)type {` without the `*`

Comment: What a dumb mistake I've made here. Thanks a lot @Larme, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, the type of `self.biometricType` is `UnsafeMutablePointer`.
You can't set `UnsafeMutablePointer` type to enum `ScreenType`.

Second, you should use full enum name to get access to obj-c enum like this example.

```
let screenType: ScreenType = ScreenType.TouchId
```

Comment: I got your point but is there any workaround for using objective type enums. Also I can not changes objective c enum as it is a part of legacy code.

Comment: Did you create a bridging-header file with your obj-c headers to use obj-c file in swift?